# CSS white border in percentual filled rectangle

Tags: html, css

[image: Look at the bottom of the image, where there is a little white slice]

I got this rectangle, which is surrounded with an outline, and filled with 25 divs, which sizes are 20% in width and height. margin and padding are 0 for each of these and it works with all other squares. I also checked the outer squara to actually be a square. That's an example for the style of one sub-square (it's copied from chrome toolbox):

```
element.style {
    left: 60%;
    top: 80%;
    width: 20%;
    height: 20%;
    float: left;
}
```

How can it happen that theres still a white space at the bottom? Can it be because of inexact float calculations?

Anyone already ran into this problem?

Comment: Could you please show your html and full css or a pointer to fiddle ??

Comment: Hmm..when are you getting this issue and what browser are you using ?? I checked your link and i see that on first time load it just works fine but once you try re-sizing the console, the issue appears

Comment: People here usually don't want to visit external websites, that's why we have live snippets for - makes it easier for everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because of browser's rounding mechanism. You're not meant to work with floating point number of pixels (how would you display something smaller than the smallest monitor display unit?), and when using percentages, that will happen automatically and the layout might change for a pixel or two on different zoom levels, window sizes, etc...

Imagine your box being 101 pixels wide/high. 20 percent of that is 20.2 pixels which the browser will render at 20 pixels. In the end you'll have 5 those squares in each row and column:

> 20 + 20 + 20 + 20 + 20 = ?

Definitely not 101, and that's what creates a blank space.

Percentages are good and have their purpose, but not for what you're doing, at least not without a little control on your end.

The quickest fix would be to modify your resize handler to resize the whole grid in steps of 5 pixels because that way each individual square would be an integer (a round number) and everything will look as you planned.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
<div class="x">
    <div class="y"></div>
    <div class="y"></div>
    <div class="y"></div>
    <div class="y"></div>
    <div class="y"></div>

    <div class="y"></div>
    <div class="y"></div>
    <div class="y"></div>
    <div class="y"></div>
    <div class="y"></div>

    <div class="y"></div>
    <div class="y"></div>
    <div class="y"></div>
    <div class="y"></div>
    <div class="y"></div>

    <div class="y"></div>
    <div class="y"></div>
    <div class="y"></div>
    <div class="y"></div>
    <div class="y"></div>

    <div class="y"></div>
    <div class="y"></div>
    <div class="y"></div>
    <div class="y"></div>
    <div class="y"></div>
</div>
```

with this:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.x {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

.y {
    width: 20%;
    height: 20%;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

you must have it:

[this is pic of up code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bowd.png)

Comment: This definitely doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

u have added the element style for the class= "field middle center"  with height of 161.5px.

the height .5px made the white space at the bottom.